# Laravel Media Library: How to get model from custom property?

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

Using Laravel Media Library, User 1 can send an image to User 2.

User 1's user ID is stored as a custom property in the media collection: 'from_user_id'

When retrieving user 2's images, how do I get the model for User 1 so that I can display their current name and username under the thumbnail?

Here's my current collection

```php
{
  "a048e97c-13b4-4654-be78-6fbdf491e029": {
    "name": "T1fQlGCfnPt10IUagmurMSnYIF03y0o81LfILZOd",
    "file_name": "foo.jpg",
    "uuid": "a048e97c-13b4-4654-be78-6fbdf491e029",
    "preview_url": "foo-preview.jpg",
    "original_url": "foo.jpg",
    "order": 1,
    "custom_properties": {
      "from_user_id": 1,
    },
    "extension": "jpg",
    "size": 31634
  }
}
```

Im trying to get something like the following for each media in the collection, but just can't work it out.

```php
{
  "a048e97c-13b4-4654-be78-6fbdf491e029": {
    "name": "T1fQlGCfnPt10IUagmurMSnYIF03y0o81LfILZOd",
    "file_name": "foo.jpg",
    "uuid": "a048e97c-13b4-4654-be78-6fbdf491e029",
    "preview_url": "foo-preview.jpg",
    "original_url": "foo.jpg",
    "order": 1,
    "custom_properties": {
      "from_user_id": 1,
    },
    "extension": "jpg",
    "size": 31634
  },
  "user": { // append a user relationship here, but how?
    "id": 1,
    "username": "foobaz",
    "email": "foo@baz.com"
  }
}
```

This is how I'm retrieving user 2's media

```php
$media = Auth::user()->getMedia('sentToMe');
```

The creator of Laravel Media Library suggested to another person to use a filter, but that just doesn't make any sense to me because I don't want to filter the collection, I want to load the User model (user 1).

This is what I've tried but, of course, it just returns the media, it doesn't get the record of user 1 along with it.

```php
$media = Auth::user()->getMedia('sentToMe')->filter(function ($media) {
    return $media->hasCustomProperty('from_user_id');
});
```

Any suggestions on to how to get user 1's information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution.

It's a bit hacky, but it's working. I'd really like to see if it's possible to do a relation on the query instead of all this `foreach` nonsense though...

```php
$medias = Auth::user()->getMedia('sentToMe');

$ids = [];
$collection = [];

foreach($medias as $media) {
    $ids[$media->id] = $media->getCustomProperty('from_user_id');
}

$users = App\Models\User::select('id', 'username', 'name', 'avatar')
    ->whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->get();

foreach($ids as $key => $value) {
    foreach($medias as $media) {
        if($key == $media->id) {
            $collection[$key]['media'] = $media;
        }
    }
    foreach($users as $user) {
        if($value == $user->id) {
            $collection[$key]['user'] = $user;
        }
    }
}

return $collection;
```

returns

```
{
  "2": {
    "media": {
      "id": 2,
      "model_type": "App\Models\User",
      "model_id": 2,
      ...
      ...
      "custom_properties": {
        "from_user_id": 1,
      },
      "original_url": "foo.jpg",
      "preview_url": "foo-preview.jpg"
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "foobaz",
      "name": "FooBaz",
      "avatar": "/avatars/foobaz.jpeg",
    }
}
```